# Magento CE: How to change position of block inside phtml file depending on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento

I'd like to switch position of block `container2` inside `view.phtml` depending on screen resolution using javascript.

catalog.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
...
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
        ...
            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>
        ...
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

view.phtml:

If resolution < x-value display this block at position right after `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>`

```
<div class="mobile">
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
</div>
```

else: it must stay on it's default place.

In javascript something like:

```
width = document.viewport.getWidth();
```

There must be ajax request and response with post variables. But I'm not sure at which place and how to combine it all together?

Answer (score 0):

for the versions that are inferior to 1.9, it can be set in the backend by configuring different types of design following some criteria system>configuration>design.

the way to make it for mobile devices is explained [here](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.fr/2013/04/add-mobile-theme-in-magento-using-add.html).

for these versions, twitter bootstrap works nice if you configure it correctly.

for 1.9, rwd is included with foundation...

hope it helps,